# Why "fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred" is a concern?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model

As discussed in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277201/is-it-possible-to-get-fitted-values-0-or-1-in-logistic-regression-when-the-fitti), perfect separation (algorithm did not converge) is a separate issue aside from "fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred".

As suggested in @gung's example, the model can be perfectly fine, even fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred.

So, why R is giving such warning? Because it might be overfitting involved?

Comment: In my experience when R gives me this warning it means I have done something truly stupid. It is a bit like: Did you really mean ...?

Comment: @mdewey ye, that is exactly my question. if you check gung's example, it can be perfectly fine, why it is warning me?

Comment: Hints: what are the logits of $0$ and $1$?  How would they be represented in floating point? What does that imply about the reliability of those representations?